# When Dependant column in DatagridView then how to filter the data because privious selected items are disappear

Tags: windows, vb.net

In my `datagridview` there are two dependent columns, one is category and the other is items. So I want to filter my item column list as per selected category.

But the problem is that when I change the category wise data to datasource of items combobox, previous selected items names disappear because previous items is not in current datasource.

So what is correct solution of such problem.

Comment: You need to add the problematic code.

Answer (score 0):

Filter columns with a Dataview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx

Depending on input validation and what not, you can update the DataSource after an edit operation.